# get unique values array javascript by property using map, reduce or filter

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this array and want to get only unique Courses and more recent DateStart.

```
const classes = [{
    Course: {id: 1, Name: 'JS'},
    Name: 'JS Morning',DateStart: "2018/09/01"
}, {
    Course: {id: 1, Name: 'JS'},
Name: 'JS Afternoon',DateStart: "2018/10/15"
}, {
    Course: {id: 1, Name: 'JS'},
    Name: 'JS Night',DateStart: "2018/10/01"
}, {
    Course: {id: 2, Name: 'Jquery'},
    Name: 'JQ Morning',DateStart: "2018/10/01"
}, {
    Course: {id: 2, Name: 'Jquery'},
    Name: 'JQ Night',DateStart: "2018/09/15"
}];
```

Per example, my result array should be:

```
const results = [{
    DataStart:"2018/09/01",Course{id: 1, Name: "JS"}
},{
    DataStart:"2018/09/15",Course{id: 2, Name: "Jquery"}
```

I know to do this using foreach, but I want to use MAP or REDUCE or FILTER. Could anybody help me?

Thanks!!!
Alex

Comment: Show us how your forEach works as well as what you tried with the other methods. Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service. Should be fairly easy to turn it into a reduce

Answer (score 0):

We could do first a `sort()` by date, in this case is easier comparing the dates as numbers, replacing the `/` like `20180901`, once we have the sorted array we could do a `filter()` to keep just the first record of a `Course.Name`.

```js
var classes = [{
    Course: {id: 1, Name: 'JS'},
    Name: 'JS Morning',DateStart: "2018/09/01"
}, {
    Course: {id: 1, Name: 'JS'},
Name: 'JS Afternoon',DateStart: "2018/10/15"
}, {
    Course: {id: 1, Name: 'JS'},
    Name: 'JS Night',DateStart: "2018/10/01"
}, {
    Course: {id: 2, Name: 'Jquery'},
    Name: 'JQ Morning',DateStart: "2018/10/01"
}, {
    Course: {id: 2, Name: 'Jquery'},
    Name: 'JQ Night',DateStart: "2018/09/15"
}];


var diff = {}

results = classes.sort((a,b)=>{

    return a.DateStart.replace(/\//g, "") - b.DateStart.replace(/\//g, ""); 
 
}).filter(a=>{
    delete a.Name
    if(a.Course.Name in diff){
        return false;
    }else{
        diff[a.Course.Name] = true;
        return true;
    }
    
})

console.log(results)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, but there is a problem... the date need to be the smaller.... thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var classes = [{
    Course: {id: 1, Name: 'JS'},
    Name: 'JS Morning',DateStart: "2018/09/01"
}, {
    Course: {id: 1, Name: 'JS'},
Name: 'JS Afternoon',DateStart: "2018/09/01"
}, {
    Course: {id: 1, Name: 'JS'},
    Name: 'JS Night',DateStart: "2018/09/01"
}, {
    Course: {id: 2, Name: 'Jquery'},
    Name: 'JQ Morning',DateStart: "2018/09/15"
}, {
    Course: {id: 2, Name: 'Jquery'},
    Name: 'JQ Night',DateStart: "2018/09/15"
}];

var result = classes.map(x => { return { DateStart: x.DateStart, Course: x.Course } }).filter((x,i,a)=> i == a.findIndex(y => y.DateStart == x.DateStart && y.Course.id == x.Course.id && y.Course.Name == x.Course.Name));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` to get the unique courses using the `id`. If you get a repeating course, then compare the `DateStart` and store the prior value. Once you get all the unique course in an object accumulator, get all values using `Object.values()`.

```js
const classes = [{ Course: {id: 1, Name: 'JS'}, Name: 'JS Morning',DateStart: "2018/09/01" }, { Course: {id: 1, Name: 'JS'}, Name: 'JS Afternoon',DateStart: "2018/10/15" }, { Course: {id: 1, Name: 'JS'}, Name: 'JS Night',DateStart: "2018/10/01" }, { Course:{id: 2, Name: 'Jquery'}, Name: 'JQ Morning',DateStart: "2018/10/01" }, { Course: {id: 2, Name: 'Jquery'}, Name: 'JQ Night',DateStart: "2018/09/15" }],
    result = Object.values(classes.reduce((r,{Course, DateStart}) => {
      if(r[Course.id]) {
        if(r[Course.id].DateStart > DateStart)
          r[Course.id] = {Course, DateStart};
      } else 
        r[Course.id] = {Course, DateStart};
      return r;
    },{}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following solution to get the unique values from an array by property using map:

```
classes.map( c => ({ DataStart: c.DateStart, Course: c.Course }))
```

Comment: Indeed map not filters just like filter dont map (transform) an array.
If you want to do both you have to use reduce. 
Provide an pastebin with your foreach and we help you transform it in a reduce function.

Comment: Yes, I want both... How can I use reduce?